# Whats the proper way to use password_verify with PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, password-encryption

I can't seem to get password_verify to work w/in my php PDO code.  My pass field is stored as varchar(255). I've been reading similar questions, but from what I can tell I have it set up right.  I must still be missing something.
My registration page is as follows..

```
$user = $_POST['username']
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
$passH = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$query = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO emps (user, pass) VALUES (?, ?)");
$query->execute([$user, $passH]);
```

An encrypted password is now successfully stored in my database.

My Login Page is as follows..

```
if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $pass = trim($_POST['pass'];
  $passH = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
  $sel_user = $con->prepare("SELECT id, username, pass, gid FROM emps WHERE gid!=4 AND username=?");
  $sel_user->execute([$username]);
  $check_user=$sel_user->fetch();
  if(count($check_user)>0 && password_verify($passH, $check_user['pass'])) {
    $_SESSION['username']=$check_user['username'];
    header("Location: xadmin.php");
    exit;
  }
  else {
    echo "<script>alert('Not Found')</script>";
```

Body of Login Page..

```
<form action="login.php" method="post">
    <table width="100%" border="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#3B3B3B" height ="35" class="BodyTxtB" align="center">Administrator Login</td></tr>
            <tr height="20"><td></td></tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="BodyTxtB" align="center">Username</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="BodyTxtB" align="center"><input type="text" class="BodyTxtBC" name="username" required="required"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr height="20"><td></td></tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="BodyTxtB" align="center">Password</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="BodyTxtB" align="center"><input type="password" class="BodyTxtBC" name="pass" required="required"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr height="20"><td></td></tr>
            <tr height="35"><td align="center"><input type="image" src="images/btn_login.jpg" name="login" value="Login"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="login" value="Login" /></td></tr>
            <tr height="20"><td></td></tr>
         </tbody>
     </table>
   </form>
```

Can anyone spot any errors?

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/password_hash

Comment: why would you hash a password before verifying it?

Comment: You're using password_hash incorrectly. You need supply the plaintext password with the hashed password (from the database). Also why are you trimming the password?

Comment: Ok, I will remove password trimming.  Also I should not have `$passH = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);`  on my login page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arguments for [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) are (1) the unhashed password you want to check and (2) the hashed password you are using as a reference. You are hashing the first argument before comparing:

```
$pass = trim($_POST['pass'];
$passH = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
// ...
if(count($check_user)>0 && password_verify($passH, $check_user['pass'])) {
```

You should be doing `password_verify($pass /** the unhashed one */, $check_user['pass'])`

Also, trimming the password is a bad idea. What if the password actually includes whitespace (which you *should* allow it to do)?

Answer (score 1):

RTM? http://php.net/password_verify

```
boolean password_verify ( string $password , string $hash )
```

You pass in the **PLAINTEXT** password for `$password`. You don't hash it yourself. That'll just generate a NEW hash with a DIFFERENT salt, making comparisons both pointless and impossible.

`password_verify` will extract the proper salt from `$hash`, use that to hash `$password` itself, then compare the hash strings.

e.g. password_verify is basically just this:

```
function password_verify($pw, $hash) {
    $salt = get_salt_from($hash);
    $temp = password_hash($pw, $salt);

    return ($temp == $hash);
}
```

Comment: It's pretty funny how PHP simplifies everything, seriously, two functions to do everything?, but people still manage to over-complicate things. $temp === $hash for that extra measure.

Comment: well, `get_salt_from()` could get a bit tricky, but otherwise, yeah. password_verify is basically just a convenience.

Comment: Thank You @MarcB for explaining this to me